# Columbus Alpha Acid?

Tags: hops

I just received a package with some supplies that I ordered, including Columbus hops. I was expecting to have Columbus with something around 12% AA, but the hops bags is labeled with only 6%, this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen Columbus that low, but I guess its possible. I would contact the seller for more details to see if they are aware of a misprint on the bags.

Comment: I called my seller, he said the label is correct. I'm not really sure about this hop, I'll buy in other place.

Comment: Wow. I am still skeptical. Perhaps contact the hop supplier directly as ask. If they verify the %, then at least you know the seller is legit. BTW, did you miss this AA% when ordering or was it not listed in the description? If it wasn't listed then I would never order from this seller again, as that is a very unusual level, and you should have been notified.

Comment: I missed to check the AA% when I was ordering, I never thought that something unusual could happen. I learned lesson, ask for AA% value before to buy.